# Service Object coming null

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to invoke a service from my MVC5 web project but that service object is coming null. Code below.

```
public class UserAuthController : Controller
    {
        private ILoginService loginService;

        // GET: UserAuth
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var response = loginService.Login("Hi", "123456789");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I could see that the "loginService" object is not initilized soit is always null.

But When I tried to initialize it with a contructor I amgetting an eror that "No parameter less ocontructor is defined" --As I have a parametrized contructor now.

```
public class UserAuthController : Controller
    {
        private ILoginService loginService;
        private IUnityContainer unityContainer;
        public UserAuthController(IUnityContainer iUnityContainer, ILoginService iLoginService)
        {
            unityContainer = iUnityContainer;
            loginService = iLoginService;
        }

        // GET: UserAuth
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var response = loginService.Login("Hi", "123456789");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with what extra steps I have to take to invoke my service ?
My service is defined in different library class in same solution.

I think I am missing some registration for this service.

Comment: did you install unity.mvc5 from nuget?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten, I have added Microsoft.Practices.Unity in my project.

Comment: Why does your `UserAuthController` have a reference to an `IUnityContainer`?   It looks like you've got the IoC / DI pattern all wrong

Comment: I have registered ILoginService and LoginService in IoCRegistration

Comment: @BenCottrell is right, i think you've got some parts missing. I suggest you google: "unity mvc5" to get started.